# Why do we need both BeginGetResponse AND BeginRead?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm looking at the following reference for making asynchronous web requests with C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

When I build the sample code with only BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse, my "asynchronous call" still takes hundreds of milliseconds to complete.

Can someone explain why the reading requires another asynchronous call, when the BeginGetResponse should already be on a separate thread?

Comment: Well you want the data to be read as soon as it's received and keep fetching new data simultaneously rather than reading all data in the buffer and fetching some more isn't it? But if you're response is a short burst then a spawning a new thread might indeed be a tad bit expensive..

Comment: Download a gigabyte file from an Internet server.  Takes a couple of seconds to get started, takes many minutes to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is mapped to underlying socket operations. BeginGetResponse establishes connection to server (that's why it takes so long) and sends the request, while BeginRead waits for response data.

Answer (score 5):

Because BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse have to do with connecting to the Http endpoint (server may take some time to respond) while BeginRead/EndRead have to do with reading a potentially long response from the response stream.

Imagine that your response takes 10 seconds to produce on the server and the amount of data it spits out is, say, 10MB.

- Without the first pair of Begin/EndGetResponse calls, your thread would be blocked for at least 10 seconds waiting for the **first byte of the response** to come back.
- Without the second set of Begin/EndRead calls, your thread would be blocked while you are reading 10MB of data one network packet at a time (remember that TCP packets have limited size so it takes a while for all of them to arrive back on the client)